# C# Compiler feature or am I loosing my mind?

Tags: c#, generics, implicit-typing

After rewriting my event invocation function to handle the events and their arguments generically, I started going over my code (to match the change), and I noticed that the compiler implicitly made the generic call.

Here's my function:

```
private void InvokeEvent<TArgs>(EventHandler<TArgs> invokedevent, TArgs args) 
    where TArgs : EventArgs
    {
        EventHandler<TArgs> temp = invokedevent;
        if (temp != null)
        {
            temp(this, args);
        }
    }
```

and here is the line to call the function:

```
InvokeEvent(AfterInteraction, result);
```

This compiles without a problem, and the intellisense even display the "correct" call (with the  part).

Is this a compiler feature (the generic type can, actually, be directly inferred from the second argument), or am I going crazy over nothing and missing the point?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the compiler can infer all type parameters then you don't need to specify them explicitly. In this case it can infer `TArgs` from the second parameter.

But if it can't infer *all* type parameters, you need to specify all of them, even the ones the compiler could infer.

Answer (score 3):

It is call type inference, read about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364047.aspx), search for the chapter "Type Inference"

Answer (score 2):

As you have said the compiler has inferred type from the second argument.